# preg_match to check for upper case of first letter of each word in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I came across this php ucfirst() to make uppercase the first character of each word in a string.

```
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucfirst($foo);
```

but how can I use use regular expression and preg_match() to check, then display the error message?

```
if (preg_match('/\b\p{Ll}/', $mem_titlename))
{
   $error = true;
   echo '<error elementid="mem_titlename" message="TITLE - please use uppercase for each word."/>';
}
```

not sure what that expression means in the example above but I got it from somewhere which does the same job as ucfirst()...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use a regular expression? It seems unnecessary if `ucwords()` does what you want. If so, just the following:

```
if (ucwords($mem_titlename) == $mem_titlename) {
   $error = true;
   echo '<error elementid="mem_titlename" message="TITLE - please use uppercase for each word."/>';
}
```

Also note that `ucwords()` does what you describe, not `ucfirst()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: +1. There is no need to use regular expressions for an easy task like this.

Comment: @You, agreed. Although a great tool, I unfortunately see them used far too often in the *wrong* instances than in the *right*.